# Receive images from server through GPRS and display

Tags: android

I need an android application that needs to receive images from a server through GPRS(by http connection) and display it. am having the url of the server

Comment: And the question is?....

Comment: Do you need the application packed up and ready for use or you need a hint in which direction to walk? If the first, you're in the wrong place and we don't have enough coffee

Answer (score 0):

Lucky you!  There's already one built in.  It's called the web browser.  You just give it a url in an intent, and it displays the content.

If what you want is something more like a library than an application, then you declare internet permission and use a webview instead of the browser.

And of course you are welcome to do the fetching and displaying all by hand, too.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm pleased to announce that a new open source sample application—called Photostream—has been added to the apps-for-android project. Photostream is a simple photos browser and viewer for Flickr. All you need to use it is a Flickr screen name or user name (the application offers a default user name if you just want to try it.)"

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/09/android-photostream.html